# Script isn't retrieving all the info

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried making a python script that gets all the fighter names and their records from boxrec.com. The issue is that it doesn't retrieve them all (Floyd Mayweather is missing) and some of them appear several times (Success Tetteh for example).

The output is too big to post it here: https://cryptpad.fr/pad/#/2/pad/view/mYd4jIMOxY7QNUqW2-5TvYIvvx84KXbiMdYvXINGV9M/

Edit: For some fighters the records are wrong (Vasyl Lomachenko for example appears to have 28 wins, but he has 14)

```
import numpy
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
import time


def main():
    fighter_names = []
    fighter_wins = []
    fighter_losses = []
    fighter_draws = []
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    site = "https://boxrec.com/en/login"
    payload = {
        '_username': username,
        '_password': password,
        'login[go]': None
    }
    with Session() as s:
        s.get(site)
        s.post(site, data=payload, headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        })

        pages = numpy.arange(1, 19152, 20)
        for page in pages:
            page = s.get(
                "https://boxrec.com/en/locations/people?l%5Brole%5D=proboxer&l%5Bdivision%5D=&l%5Bcountry%5D=&l"
                "%5Bregion%5D=&l%5Btown%5D=&l_go=&offset= "
                + str(page))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            names_a = soup.find_all('a', class_='personLink')
            if not names_a:
                print("solving captcha")
                page = s.get(
                    "https://boxrec.com/en/locations/people?l%5Brole%5D=proboxer&l%5Bdivision%5D=&l%5Bcountry%5D=&l"
                    "%5Bregion%5D=&l%5Btown%5D=&l_go=&offset= "
                    + str(page))
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
                names_a = soup.find_all('a', class_='personLink')
                pyautogui.click(x=118, y=1061)
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.click(x=1035, y=619)
                time.sleep(2)
                pyautogui.click(x=97, y=59)
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.click(x=834, y=247)
                time.sleep(2)
                if not names_a:
                    print("please solve captcha manually")
                while not names_a:
                    page = s.get(
                        "https://boxrec.com/en/locations/people?l%5Brole%5D=proboxer&l%5Bdivision%5D=&l%5Bcountry%5D=&l"
                        "%5Bregion%5D=&l%5Btown%5D=&l_go=&offset= "
                        + str(page))
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
                    names_a = soup.find_all('a', class_='personLink')
            wins_span = soup.find_all('span', class_='textWon')
            loses_span = soup.find_all('span', class_='textLost')
            draws_span = soup.find_all('span', class_='textDraw')
            for container in names_a:
                name = container.text
                print(name)
                fighter_names.append(name)

            for container in wins_span:
                wins = container.text
                fighter_wins.append(wins)

            for container in loses_span:
                losses = container.text
                fighter_losses.append(losses)

            for container in draws_span:
                draws = container.text
                fighter_draws.append(draws)

    fighters = {
        "name": fighter_names,
        "wins": fighter_wins,
        "loses": fighter_losses,
        "draws": fighter_draws
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fighters, orient="index")
    df = df.transpose()
    df.to_csv("fighters.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refrain from using the same variable name to represent 2 separate things...Looks like you have `page` variable being used in 2 separate instances, which can be confusing.

As far as some of the issues, I'm assuming at some point there's a mismatch in the lists so the corresponding data isn't lining up with the correct fighter name, etc. or there's something off with the sites actual data/html. Not entirely sure as I haven't debugged. Reason being, have you considered using pandas to parse the table then just split the `'w-l-d'` column? I think it would be far easier to let pandas do the parsing as to not miss something in the 900+ pages you need to go through.

See if this helps:

```
import numpy
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
import time
import math


def main():
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    site = "https://boxrec.com/en/login"
    payload = {
        '_username': username,
        '_password': password,
        'login[go]': None
    }
    with Session() as s:
        s.get(site)
        s.post(site, data=payload, headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        })

        pages = numpy.arange(1, 19152, 20)
        for page in pages:
            response = s.get(
                "https://boxrec.com/en/locations/people?l%5Brole%5D=proboxer&l%5Bdivision%5D=&l%5Bcountry%5D=&l"
                "%5Bregion%5D=&l%5Btown%5D=&l_go=&offset= "
                + str(page))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
            names_a = soup.find_all('a', class_='personLink')
            if not names_a:
                print("solving captcha")
                response = s.get(
                    "https://boxrec.com/en/locations/people?l%5Brole%5D=proboxer&l%5Bdivision%5D=&l%5Bcountry%5D=&l"
                    "%5Bregion%5D=&l%5Btown%5D=&l_go=&offset= "
                    + str(page))
                soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
                names_a = soup.find_all('a', class_='personLink')
                pyautogui.click(x=118, y=1061)
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.click(x=1035, y=619)
                time.sleep(2)
                pyautogui.click(x=97, y=59)
                time.sleep(1)
                pyautogui.click(x=834, y=247)
                time.sleep(2)
                if not names_a:
                    print("please solve captcha manually")
                while not names_a:
                    response = s.get(
                        "https://boxrec.com/en/locations/people?l%5Brole%5D=proboxer&l%5Bdivision%5D=&l%5Bcountry%5D=&l"
                        "%5Bregion%5D=&l%5Btown%5D=&l_go=&offset= "
                        + str(page))
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
                    names_a = soup.find_all('a', class_='personLink')
                    
            df = pd.read_html(response.text)[-1] 
            df = df[['name','w-l-d']]
            df = df[df['w-l-d'].astype(str).str.match(r"(^\d*.\d*.\d*$)")]  # <--- ADD THIS LINE
            df[['wins','loses','draws']] = df['w-l-d'].str.split(expand=True)
            df = df.drop('w-l-d', axis=1)
            
            print('Page: %d of %d' %(((page-1)/20)+1,math.ceil(19152/20)))
        
            final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    final_df.to_csv("fighters.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It worked. But Floyd Mayweather is still missing. I checked and it seems that retired boxers are missing the most and I thought I should use another link from boxrec: https://boxrec.com/en/ratings?r%5Brole%5D=proboxer&r%5Bsex%5D=M&r%5Bdivision%5D=&r%5Bcountry%5D=&r%5Bstance%5D=&r%5Bstatus%5D=&r_go=&offset=0   this is the code: https://bpa.st/LWMA but it raises this error: https://bpa.st/ISYQ

Comment: Ok. I’ll take a look at it later and see what’s going on.

Comment: I edited the code. You need to add 1 line to remove any non w-l-d records that's coming with the table. See edit above where I added the 1 line `df = df[df['w-l-d'].astype(str).str.match(r"(^\d*.\d*.\d*$)")]`